# Zebra Omnii XT15

Tags: barcode-scanner

I have a zebra omnii XT15 that we are experimenting with, and I am having trouble with some barcode scanning.
I can scan 12 digit codes just fine, but am having troubles getting a 14 digit code to scan. I have gone into the settings and made sure the length restrictions encompassed the amount of data I need, but am still having no luck. I'm just too unfamiliar with the barcode settings within this gun.
We also received some symbol guns in, but they worked correctly out of the box. I have attached some images of the different barcodes I am trying to scan below.

14 digit code:
[image: 14 digit code]
12 digit code:
[image: 12 digit code]

Answer (score 0):

Those two barcodes are different symbologies, the 14 digit code is i2of5 (or some variant thereof, I am not an expert) and the 12 digit code is UPCA.  I suggest you ensure the correct decoders are enabled on the XT15